# Is Bitnami Lampstack ebs eligible for AWS free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami

I am considering installing the Bitnami Lampstack ebs on AWS, but I wanted to make sure that it is still free of charge to use if I don't go over the limits. There was no clear documentation of this online. If anyone knows please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your Amazon account qualifies for the free tier (was created after October 2010) you should be able to run any of the available [BitNami](http://bitnami.org) images for free. We do it all the time (I am one of the BitNami developers :)

Comment: I just tried setting up an AWS AMI with the LAMP Bitnami Stack and they're charging .02/hr... I thought they were free?

Comment: The BitNami AMIs are completely free. The 0.02/h is being charged by Amazon for running it in their infrastructure. If you qualify for their free tier, you should not be charged though